# Regex to match exact phrase before certain word

Tags: regex

I would like to match any four digits occurring before double space and word "from"  ex.

- `2356  from`
- `1524  from`
- `1223  from`

The expression `\d{4}  from` extracts digits, double space and the word "from", but ideally I would like to get only those four digits (without the trailing spaces and word "from") and only in cases when they are not part of number with hyphen like this example:

- `2536  from` = `2536`
- `8574  from` = `8574`
- `35-6655  from` = no match
- `3652` = no match (number without word "from" after the digits)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use either grouping `(...)` operators in your regex:

```
(\d{4})  from
```

and then extract group #1 from the match.  Or a zero-width look-ahead match using `(?=...)`.

```
\d{4}(?=  from)
```

To avoiding a match following the hyphen, you can use a zero-width negative look-behind.

```
(?<!-)\d{4}(?=  from)
```

Explanation:

`(?<!_)_______________` negative zero-width look-behind ...
`____-________________` ... doesn't match if a `"-"` is found
`______\d{4}__________` four digits
`___________(?=______)` positive zero-width look-ahead ...
`______________  from_` ... matches if `"  from"` is found

Answer (score 0):

You can do by `([0-9]{4})  from`

More see in [here](https://regex101.com/r/udDh6M/2)